# Symfony2 Many to One relation

Tags: symfony, relation

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I have a question and hope you can help me. I'm new to Symfony2 and try to establish a Many to One relationship. But It doesn't work.

At first my two mySQL tables:

### TABLE user

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `user_account_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_log_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

ALTER TABLE `user`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`), ADD KEY `role_id` (`role_id`);

ALTER TABLE `user`
MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

ALTER TABLE `user`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `rolle` (`id`);
```

### TABLE rolle

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rolle` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

ALTER TABLE `rolle`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `rolle`
MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

### The mapping: User.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User" table="user" repository-class="dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\UserRepository">
    <indexes>
      <index name="role_id" columns="role_id"/>
    </indexes>
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint name="username" columns="username"/>
      <unique-constraint name="email" columns="email"/>
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="40" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="127" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="128" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="isActive" type="boolean" column="is_active" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="salt" type="string" column="salt" length="40" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="userAccountCreated" type="datetime" column="user_account_created" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="userLogDate" type="datetime" column="user_log_date" nullable="false"/>
    <many-to-one field="role" target-entity="Rolle">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="role_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

### The mapping: Rolle.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle" table="rolle">
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint name="id" columns="id"/>
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="40" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="role" type="string" column="role" length="40" nullable="false"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

### The User Entity: User.php

```
namespace dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $userAccountCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $userLogDate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rolle")
     * @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/

    private $role;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->role = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt) {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle $role
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole(\dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle $role = null) {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle 
     */
    public function getRole() {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set userAccountCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userAccountCreated
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserAccountCreated($userAccountCreated) {
        $this->userAccountCreated = $userAccountCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userAccountCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserAccountCreated() {
        return $this->userAccountCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLogDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLogDate
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserLogDate($userLogDate) {
        $this->userLogDate = $userLogDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLogDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUserLogDate() {
        return $this->userLogDate;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // UserInterface

    public function getRoles() {
        return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    // AdvancedUserInterface

    public function isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    // serialize and unserialize must be updated - see below
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->isActive
                ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

}
```

### The Rolle Entity: Rolle.php

```
<?php

namespace dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Roles
 */
class Rolle {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Roles
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return Roles
     */
    public function setRole($role) {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRole() {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

I execute the following controller and always get a stack overflow.

```
public function testAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('dummyDashboardBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id'=>'1'));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($entity );
    echo '</pre>';
    return new Response('');
}
```

This is the output:

```
dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User Object
(
    [username:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => blabla
    [password:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => $2a$12$8VsqiLcFSiDQx/LBdJrmtuvxUG523WS1
    [email:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => blabla@web.de
    [isActive:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => 1
    [salt:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [userAccountCreated:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-02-17 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [userLogDate:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-02-17 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [id:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => 1
    [role:dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\User:private] => Proxies\__CG__\dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle Object
        (
            [__initializer__] => Closure Object
                (
                    [static] => Array
                        (
                            [entityPersister] => Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister Object
                                (
                                    [class:protected] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle
                                            [namespace] => dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity
                                            [rootEntityName] => dummy\DashboardBundle\Entity\Rolle
                                            [customGeneratorDefinition] => 
                                            [customRepositoryClassName] => 
                                            [isMappedSuperclass] => 
                                            [parentClasses] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [subClasses] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [namedQueries] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [namedNativeQueries] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [sqlResultSetMappings] => Array
```

...

Actually - I expect the values of the first row from the user table like  username, password, email, isActive, salt, userAccountCreated, userLogDate and the role value from table rolle as output. But as you can see, instead of the role value from the 2nd table i get an overflow. Do you have any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its a user entity object try to call its getters in order to get the values like `$entity->getUsername()` etc

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user roles by using:

```
$entity->getRole();
```

In the above examples, two queries were made - one for the original object (e.g. a User) and one for the related object(s) (e.g. the Role objects). You can avoid the second query by issuing a join in the original query:

```
 ...
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT u, r FROM User u
            JOIN user.role r
            WHERE u.id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $id);

    try {
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

[Read more about joining related objects](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records)